# Как лучше поменять структуру своего компилятора ассемблера LC-3?

Tags: python, ассемблер, компилятор

Пишу компилятор (ради тренировки на питоне, потом перенесу на С) ассемблера для LC-3. Сделал такую структуру:

1) Очередная строка передается в лексер, который возвращает список токенов

2) Синтаксический анализатор проверяет список токенов на принадлежность к языку с помощью метода рекурсивного списка (каждому нетерминалу грамматики соответствует своя функция). По ходу работы синт.анализатор строит простое дерево. Значение корня дерева - "LABEL" или "COMMAND". У корня максимум (!) 3 потомка, т.к. по спецификации ассемблера LC-3 у команды может быть как раз максимум 3 операнда. Вот так дерево выглядит у меня в коде:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.root = value
        self.childs = []

    def append(self, value):
        self.childs.append(value)
```

Встречаем новый операнд - вызываем tree.append(operand).

3) Синт.анализатор возвращает это дерево (parse_tree в коде) и основной цикл передает его контекстному анализатору, объединенному с стадией генерации машинного кода. Например, вот описание команды ADD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

DR, SR1, SR2 - регистры, imm5 - 5 битное число. Мой контекстный анализатор видит, что parse_tree.root == "ADD", поэтому запускает такую функцию:

```
def add(parse_tree):
    # У ADD 3 операнда!
    if len(parse_tree.childs) != 3:
        prerror("Invalid combination of opcode and operands")

    op1, op2, op3 = parse_tree.childs[0], parse_tree.childs[1], parse_tree.childs[2]

    # первые два операнда всегда регистры
    if op1 not in REGISTERS or op2 not in REGISTERS:
        prerror("Invalid combination of opcode and operands")
    # если третий операнд ни число, ни регистр, то ошибка
    if op3 not in REGISTERS and not isint(op3):
        prerror("Invalid combination of opcode and operands")
    # если третий операнд число, и при этом больше 32 (вспоминаем про 5 бит), то выдаем соответствующую ошибку
    if isint(op3):
        if int(op3) >= 2**5:
            prerror("The number is out of range")

    # в COMMANDS["ADD"] содержится число 0b0001, то есть код команды ADD
    ADDcode = COMMANDS["ADD"]
    # а в REGISTERS лежат числовые значения для каждого из 8 регистров
    OP1code, OP2code, OP3code = REGISTERS[op1], REGISTERS[op2], 0

    if isint(op3):
        OP3code = int(op3)
    else:
        OP3code = REGISTERS[op3]

    # здесь формируется машинный код этой команды
    instruction = (ADDcode << 12) + (OP1code << 9) + (OP2code << 6) + OP3code

    return instruction
```

Насколько вообще такая структура компилятора оптимальна? Да, делаю это все из интереса и ради тренировки, но все-таки хочу написать нормальную структуру компилятора, а не абы как. Дело в том, что вот такие проверки для каждой из команд (17 штук) занимают кучу кода (450-500 строк у меня занял контекстный анализатор). Это нормально, или можно как-нибудь оптимизировать все это дело? И вообще, насколько правильно то, что я соединил контекстный анализ и генерацию кода?

Comment: Кста, а `bison` и `flex` к питону не пристёгиваются?

Comment: Скорее всего у вас будет несколько похожих команд, различающихся только опкодом (ADD, SUB, возможно еще какие-то). Для них можно использовать одну и ту же функцию. То же самое с другими однотипными командами. В идеале должна быть вообще одна функция и таблица с описанием всех видов команд с количеством и типом операндов.

Comment: Посмотреть, как пишутся кросс-ассемблеры, можно, например, здесь: https://github.com/luisos/asm80.py (это кросс-ассемблер для популярного в прошлом 8-разрядного микропроцессора Intel 8080)